# MySQL query on max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have for example these 2 tables:

```
Organiser        Events 
----------       -------
id         1     id
           |__ * organiser_id
                 date
                 status
```

How do I select the ids of all organisers who's latest event it's status equals for example 'active'.

I think I have to use max(date) in maybe a subquery or do I need to use a join? Still haven't found the solution, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT:

I just found this solution (dunno if this is the best one?):

```
SELECT o.id, e.date
FROM Organiser o
INNER JOIN events e on e.organiser_id = o.id
WHERE e.date = (SELECT max(date) 
                FROM events e2
                WHERE e2.organiser_id = o.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
      id
FROM 
      Organiser AS o
WHERE 
      ( SELECT status
        FROM Events AS e
        WHERE e.organiser_id = o.id
        ORDER BY `date` DESC
        LIMT 1
      ) = 'active'
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT o.name, ep.date 
FROM ( SELECT date,max(id) AS maxDateID FROM events es GROUP BY date ) md
INNER JOIN events ep ON ep.id=md.id
INNER JOIN organiser o ON o.id=ep.organiser_id
WHERE e.status='active'
```

[`REFERENCE`](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/24/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-on-a-unique-column/)